# Why makefile requests folder for generated file

Tags: makefile

I wrote a makefile to compile for generated file

```
%.o: %.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

default: gen main.o

gen:
    touch main.cc
```

And got

```
$ make default
touch main.cc
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

But if I add a folder for the generated .cc and .o files, it works

```
obj/%.o: src/%.cc
    g++ -c $< -o $@

default: gen obj/main.o

gen:
    touch src/main.cc
```

Why the folder obj and src are requested

Answer (score 1):

They're not. This behavior comes from `make`'s optimizations and your `Makefile` not being sincere about what it is doing.

When `make` reads a directory, it hashes all the directory contents and performs future file lookups in this [hash](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/make.git/tree/src/dir.c#n602). When `make` starts for the first time, there is no `main.cc` file, so the directory hash does not contain an entry for `main.cc`. Since your `Makefile` generates this file, but does not declare it, `make` does not know that there is a target that generates `main.cc` file and when it looks up in the hash, the file is not there. Therefore your implicit rule is rejected as impossible:

```
$ make -dr default
...
Considering target file 'default'.
 File 'default' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'default'.
 No implicit rule found for 'default'.
  Considering target file 'gen'.
   File 'gen' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'gen'.
  Must remake target 'gen'.
touch main.cc
Putting child 0x55de3daaa6a0 (gen) PID 6075 on the chain.
Live child 0x55de3daaa6a0 (gen) PID 6075
Reaping winning child 0x55de3daaa6a0 PID 6075
Removing child 0x55de3daaa6a0 PID 6075 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file 'gen'.
  Considering target file 'main.o'.
   File 'main.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.cc'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.cc'.
   Looking for a rule with intermediate file 'main.cc'.
    Avoiding implicit rule recursion.
   No implicit rule found for 'main.o'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'main.o'.
  Must remake target 'main.o'.
make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

If you `strace` this invocation, you will notice two things: a) a `getdents64` call that reads directory contents (used for lookup and hash) and b) lack of `stat` for `main.cc` at all, meaning that there is no check for file existence on the disk, since its presence was resolved from cache:

```
$ strace make -r default
...
stat(".", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC|O_DIRECTORY) = 3
fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=4096, ...}) = 0
getdents64(3, /* 3 entries */, 32768)   = 80
getdents64(3, /* 0 entries */, 32768)   = 0
close(3)                                = 0
...
stat("gen", 0x7fff4f66a3d0)             = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat("main.o", 0x7fff4f66a460)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
... <-- locale-related calls for error message
write(2, "make: *** No rule to make target"..., 71make: *** No rule to make target 'main.o', needed by 'default'.  Stop.
```

Now if you rerun the same command it will succeed, because `main.cc` file is already created and available when the directory is cached:

```
$ make -dr default
...
Considering target file 'default'.
 File 'default' does not exist.
 Looking for an implicit rule for 'default'.
 No implicit rule found for 'default'.
  Considering target file 'gen'.
   File 'gen' does not exist.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'gen'.
  Must remake target 'gen'.
touch main.cc
Putting child 0x555646acc6a0 (gen) PID 6079 on the chain.
Live child 0x555646acc6a0 (gen) PID 6079
Reaping winning child 0x555646acc6a0 PID 6079
Removing child 0x555646acc6a0 PID 6079 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file 'gen'.
  Considering target file 'main.o'.
   File 'main.o' does not exist.
   Looking for an implicit rule for 'main.o'.
   Trying pattern rule with stem 'main'.
   Trying implicit prerequisite 'main.cc'.
   Found an implicit rule for 'main.o'.
    Considering target file 'main.cc'.
     Looking for an implicit rule for 'main.cc'.
     No implicit rule found for 'main.cc'.
     Finished prerequisites of target file 'main.cc'.
    No need to remake target 'main.cc'.
   Finished prerequisites of target file 'main.o'.
  Must remake target 'main.o'.
g++ -c main.cc -o main.o
Putting child 0x555646ad0690 (main.o) PID 6080 on the chain.
Live child 0x555646ad0690 (main.o) PID 6080
Reaping winning child 0x555646ad0690 PID 6080
Removing child 0x555646ad0690 PID 6080 from chain.
  Successfully remade target file 'main.o'.
 Finished prerequisites of target file 'default'.
Must remake target 'default'.
Successfully remade target file 'default'.
```

If you play by the rules and write your `Makefile` correctly, declaring the files that are being created, `make` will run as expected:

```
$ cat Makefile
%.o: %.cc
        g++ -c $< -o $@

default: main.o

main.cc:
        touch $@

$ make default
touch main.cc
g++ -c main.cc -o main.o
```